# How to get know that name Helpers in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, helper

i have routes,

```
resources :categories do
resources :products
end
```

How can i check the names of all helper created in Rails app,

in the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

there is documentation, but can i list down names so that i can see and use the helper name easily.

**Updated:**
After some research on it, i found that "resources: categerories" known as REST full resources, and  "resources" generates the code like, "categories_path, categories, edit_category_path, new_category etc.. "

Now my question was how can list down the code which is generated for "resource :cateogires do resources :products end "

like, edit_category_product_path, i want to know the all path code that is generated for this nested resources. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First column of the output of `rake routes` + `_path` or `_url`

Comment: ok,  got it, by Entering "rake routes" on rails cmd  it displays all generated paths. Thanks